# Spring Thymeleaf prefill input with ZonedDateTime

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, java-time

Today I am having some trouble with `java.time` and `Thymeleaf`

I have a form allowing users to edit an object. I have to prefill the form inputs with the current attributes of the object. This works in most cases. The only case that does not work is when i try to fill a date input with the value of a ZonedDateTime.

Here is the input:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" th:field="*{startDate}">
```

and here is the attribute declaration:

```
private ZonedDateTime startDate;
```

Do you have any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you see anything in your input or is it completely empty?

Comment: instead of using th:field use id, name and th:value

Comment: @timothyclifford the input is completely empty